# Using regex multiple capture groups to split up a string

Tags: regex, capture-group

I have a file that looks like this...

```
"1234567123456","V","0","0","BLAH","BLAH","BLAH","BLAH"
"1234567123456","D","TEST1 "
"1234567123456","D","TEST 2~TEST3"
"1234567123456","R","TEST4~TEST5"
"1234567123457","V","0","0","BLAH","BLAH","BLAH","BLAH"
"1234567123457","D","TEST 6"
"1234567123457","D","TEST7"
"1234567123457","R","TEST 8~TEST9~TEST,10"
```

All I'm trying to do is parse the D and R lines.  The ~ is used in this case as a separator.  So the end results would be...

```
"1234567123456","V","0","0","BLAH","BLAH","BLAH","BLAH"
"1234567123456","D","TEST1 "
"1234567123456","D","TEST3"
"1234567123456","D","TEST3"
"1234567123456","R","TEST4"
"1234567123456","R","TEST5"
"1234567123457","V","0","0","BLAH","BLAH","BLAH","BLAH"
"1234567123457","D","TEST 6"
"1234567123457","D","TEST7"
"1234567123457","R","TEST 8"
"1234567123457","R","TEST9"
"1234567123457","R","TEST,10"
```

I'm using regex on applications like Textpad and Notepad++.  I have not figured out how to use a regex like **/.+/g** because the applications do not like the forward slashes.  So I don't think I can use things like the global modifier.  I currently have the following regex...

```
//In a program like Textpad/Notepad++
<FIND> "(.{13})","D","([^~]*)~(.*)
<REPLACE> "\1","D","\2"\n"\1","D","\3
```

Now if I run a find and replace with the above params a few times it would work fine (for the D lines only).  The problem is there is an unknown number of lines to be made.  For example...

```
"1234567123456","D","TEST1~TEST2~TEST3~TEST4~TEST5"
"1234567123457","D","TEST1~TEST2~TEST3"
"1234567123458","D","TEST1~TEST2"
"1234567123459","D","TEST1~TEST2~TEST3~TEST4"
```

I was hoping to be able to use a MULTI capture group to make this work.  I found this [PAGE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) talking about the common mistake between repeating a capturing group and capturing a repeated group.  I need to capture a repeated group.  For some reason I just could not make mine work right though.  Anyone else have an idea?

Note: If I could get rid of the leading and trailing spaces EX: "1234567123456","D","TEST1 " ending up as "1234567123456","D","TEST1" that would be even better but not necessary.

---

**RESOURCES:**

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html
- http://regex101.com/

Comment: Sorry to ask that, but why did you accept a wrong answer to your previous question?

Comment: I struggled with what to do but trying to be fair, it was a different question and what I asked to do @vks did answer it right and his solution did what I asked.  When I tried to apply it to my situation on a broader scale it did not work at all.  It ended up matching everything.  In my case on the first question I only had a single line to work with.  On this question there is 8.  When I tried to alter the other question (which was satisfied) it just became a mess.  In the end, I just wanted to be fair to vks.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible with a single regex in a text editor (that most of the time use the pcre regex engine), but it's possible if you decide to use C# (or an other language that use the .net framework)

Comment: Thanks Casimir.  I thought that might be the answer...  :/  I was hoping for a line by line solution...

Comment: An other option may be to use the macro capabilities of your text editor.